# OOP (Object oriented programming)

Tags: oop

I want to start studying OOP. any idea how to start?

Can any one provide me books or videos.

And what else i have to know to be good WEB developer.

I know HTML, CSS, Javascript (jQuery), PHP, MySQL.

i will be thankful for your helps.

thanks for all.

Comment: start here: http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Gang of Four website.  It's a good place to start for patterns.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/GofPatterns.aspx

This one looks promising as well...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep

Answer (score 0):

> Imperative languages use sequencing, decisions and repetition as their  main problem solving methods. Variables are created to store data and  be processed. Procedural Programming uses always a top down approach.  When we were executing the procedural codes, it starts from beginning  and ends in the bottom. With this simple snippet code, we can do a  simple arithmetic operation. Object-oriented languages are good when  you have a fixed set of operations on things and as your code evolves, you primarily add new things. This can be accomplished by adding new classes which implement existing methods and the existing classes are left alone. In object-oriented programming it calls the object when it needed instead of getting it all the time. This may save process load and memory of the computer. Event driven programming always use to event trigger functions. The overriding motivation for introducing programming languages based on different paradigms is to increase  programmer productivity. A Paradigm can be thought of as a  philosophical or theoretical framework. This framework is then used as  the basis of a new way of showing problems.

---

**start here:**
http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/

Comment: Did you get that from a website? If so, please provide a link. Otherwise, why is it in a block quote?

Comment: This is the answer I wrote. And on some website I took referrals

Comment: https://www.educative.io/blog/object-oriented-programming or  https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/object-oriented-programming-OOP